# Chrome.exe doesn't respond after update HTC vive station firmware

Tags: google-chrome, firmware, webvr

today I've done the last update of bases stations of an htc vive, but now when I'm launching a WebVR application steamVR tell me that VR is available but Chrome.exe doesn't respond...

I've updated my Graphic card : GTX 1080
I've re-installed steam / steamVR
Tried to revert the update but didn't find any way to do it.
Restart the PC
Re-installed chrome

I'm a bit lost if someone has the same problem ... Or know how to revert to a previous version of base station firmware it would be great.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may or may not be a problem with the base station firmware. There is currently an issue with Vive and Chrome – [see this tweet from Brandon Jones](https://twitter.com/Tojiro/status/826893119715057664)